# Why is the following gauge transformation singular?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gauge-theory

Suppose I have a single particle Hamiltonian: $H=\frac{p^2}{2m}+\frac{\hbar k_0}{m}\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}$, either for boson or fermion. I do a gauge transformation
$e^{-ik_0\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{r}}$ to the field operator, then the Hamiltonian will be $H'=\frac{p^2}{2m}$. My question is, is there anything wrong with this gauge transformation?

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: I havn't found the error of this transformation, but if it is correct, it will be unreasonable.

Comment: I see. I have made a mistake...

Comment: If you have figure it out, please consider post the answer here :)

Comment: When doing this transformation, the gauge field term $\hbar k_0\vec{\sigma}$ is also changed, due to the noncommutating relations between pauli matrix. So the new Hamiltonian is not $\frac{p^2}{2m}$, but a more complex form.